# List of two different tables by Id on Symfony

Tags: symfony

**hello, I'm beguiner on development, I'm working on Symfony 2.8

I'v two tables: Adherent and Ayantdroit. And Adherent has ayantdroit. 
I wanna make a list of "One Adherent" and "his different Ayantdroits". To make a choice of just One of them in my form. And how to manage it on the view.

```html
/**
     * Creates a new BonSoin entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new/{id}", name="bonsoin_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, Adherent $id, AyantDroit $ayantDroit)
    {
        $bonSoin = new BonSoin();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $nom = $em->getRepository('SkyMainBundle:Adherent')->find($id).' ' .$ayantDroit = $em->getRepository('SkyMainBundle:AyantDroit')->findByAdherent($id);
        $form = $this->createForm('Sky\MainBundle\Form\BonSoinType', $bonSoin);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           // $bonSoin->setAdherent($adherent);
            $em->persist($bonSoin);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('liste_bon_adherent', array('id' => $nom->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('bonsoin/new.html.twig', array(
            'bonsoin' => $bonSoin,
            'ayant' => $ayantDroit,
            'adherent'=> $id,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

**

Comment: Really incomprehensive question. What is this:  $nom = $em->getRepository('SkyMainBundle:Adherent')->find($id).' ' .$ayantDroit = $em->getRepository('SkyMainBundle:AyantDroit')->findByAdherent($id);?

Comment: $nom ( is how I want to call the facultative variable which can take one of my parametters ( $adherent or $ayantdroit)

Comment: But I dont know if it is like that they do concatanation in a controller

Answer (score 0):

I'v not yet get the right way, but I took an alternative solution u duplicate controllers and views.

But I really need to make the two entities use the same controller and the same view